# Curly braces, word boundaries and preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Why does the 2nd case not make the replacement? Isn't '}' a non-word character?  Including the forward slash is necessary in the original code that I was working on.

```
// Works
$s = 'abc/stringToReplace-ABC';
$pattern = '/\b\/stringToReplace\b/';
$s2 = preg_replace($pattern, '/-replacement', $s);
echo $s2 . PHP_EOL;     // output: abc/-replacement-ABC

// Doesn't work.
$s = 'abc}/stringToReplace-ABC';
$pattern = '/\b\/stringToReplace\b/';
$s2 = preg_replace($pattern, '/-replacement', $s);
echo $s2 . PHP_EOL;     // output: abc}/stringToReplace-ABC
```

Comment: `\b` is only matched before or after a word character whereas `}` and `/` are both non-word characters. There is no need to use `\b` just before `/` in your regex.

Comment: `}` is a non-word char, but `\b` - before a non-word char like `/` - requires a word char before it. Use unambiguous word boundaries, `(?<!\w)...(?!\w)`, or whitespace ones, `(?<!\S)...(?!\S)`